# Equivalente ao Form.ShowDialog() do C# em Java

Tags: java, c#, swing

Estou começando agora em Java, tem um recurso que utilizo muito no C# que é `NomeDaTela.ShowDialog();`. Queria saber um código semelhante que faça a mesma coisa no Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depende muito da api que estiver usando. Em swing, normalmente os componentes [**top level**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) que herdam de [`java.awt.Window`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html)(como `JFrame` e `JDialog`)  possuem um método `setVisible(boolean)`, que serve para tornar o componente visível ou não na aplicação.

Já componentes que herdam de [`JComponent`](http://javax.swing.JComponent), seja um componente também do tipo Container(como [`JPanel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html)) ou não(como [`JButton`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html) e [`JLabel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html)), também possuem este método para definir sua visibilidade dentro de outros containers.

Na documentação há mais detalhes sobre cada componente e seu uso, você pode ver nos links abaixo:

[Lesson: Getting Started with Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/start/index.html)

[Lesson: Using Swing Components](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html)

Comment: Eu pesquisei sobre isso, o setVisible ele abre a form que eu especificar, mas tem um detalhe que showDialog do c# faz que me ajuda muito, ele impossibilita de clicar na form anterior que tbm esta aberta, é como se fosse aquelas caixas de diálogos que te obrigam a clicar em OK para continuar. Eu quero fazer isso com uma form qualquer do meu programa em JAVA. VI que no JAVA tem uma ferramenta [JOptionPane.showInputDialog] que faz isso, mas não do jeito que eu quero pois ele só abre uma janelinha de aviso onde posso fazer as alterações de texto.

Comment: @RodolfoSouza então sua pergunta está ampla demais e não é possivel responder, pois eu teria que explicar o funcionamento de quase todas as classes que tem esse comportamento e isso foge do escopo do site. E este comportamento se chama modal, é possivel no java através de [JDialogs](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jdialog). Dê uma olhada no link para ver algumas perguntas sobre isso, algumas tem exemplos funcionais. Acesse os links da resposta para aprender sobre estes componentes também, é importante entender seu funcionamento.

Comment: Realmente, terei que criar através do JDialog.

Comment: Peguei como base a sua resposta em outro fórum.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi meu problema assim:
Criei um JDialog e fui modificando até ficar do jeito que eu queria.

```
                JDialog d = new JDialog(this, true);
                JButton BtnOK = new JButton("OK");
                JLabel lb1 = new JLabel();

                d.setLayout(null); // libera a edição do layout

                BtnOK.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { // atribui ação para o botão
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        d.dispose();
                    }
                });

                lb1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Interfaces/Imagens/hqdefault.jpg"))); // NOI18N
                lb1.setSize(485,360);
                lb1.setLocation(10, 11);

                BtnOK.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
                BtnOK.setBackground(Color.RED);
                BtnOK.setSize(480,36); 
                BtnOK.setLocation(10,380);

                d.add(BtnOK);
                d.add(lb1);
                d.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                d.setTitle("Errrrrrrrrrrrrrrou!");
                d.setSize(514, 460);
                d.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                d.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                d.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Sua resposta ficou deslocada, pois a pergunta alem de ampla, questiona algo mais teórico, e não pede a solução de um problema em especifico.

Comment: No caso para ser valida a minha resposta eu terei que explicar oque eu fiz?